# Plot neural network of a finalModel using neuralnet and caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, neural-network, r-caret

I created a function to run neural networks in R using the `neuralnet` and `caret` packages:

```
softplus <- function(x) log(1+exp(x))

nn_ribs <- function(formula, train, pre_mdl) {
  caret::train(formula, data = predict(pre_mdl, train), 
               method = "neuralnet", 
               tuneGrid = tune.grid.neuralnet,
               metric = "RMSE",
               stepmax = 100000,
               learningrate = 0.01,  
               threshold = 0.01,
               act.fct = softplus, 
               trControl = trainControl (
                 method = "repeatedcv", # cv(esto es solo crossvalidation)
                 number  = 10,  # Number of folds of the cv
                 repeats = 10,  # Number of cv repetitions, solo cuando method=repeatedcv
                 p = 0.8,       # proportion of sample to be used as train set
                 verboseIter = TRUE,
                 savePredictions = TRUE,
                 allowParallel = TRUE))
}
```

With this combination of possible neurons in three hidden layers:

```
tune.grid.neuralnet <- expand.grid(
  layer1 = c(1:5), # first hidden layer, from 1 to 5 neurons
  layer2 = c(0:5), # second hidden layer, from 0 to 5 neurons
  layer3 = c(0:5)  # third hidden layer, from 0 to 5 neurons
)
```

I later use `lapply()` to run `nn_ribs()` over different regressions (stored in `comb_A`).

```
nn_A   <- lapply(comb_A, nn_ribs)
```

If I select one of the neural network analysis in `nn_A`, I can get the combination of measured with lowest RMSE, so that it is the best model.

```
nn_A[[6]]$bestTune
   layer1 layer2 layer3
21      1      3      2
```

This indicates that the best combination is 1 neuron in layer1, 3 in layer 2 and 2 in layer 3.

When I plot the neural network, I can see it properly (all neurons per hidden layer):

```
plot(nn_A[[6]]$finalModel)
```

[image]

However, when I use another model and see the best neuron combination and plot it, I realize that the number of neurons per hidden layer are not properly represented.

```
> nn_A[[4]]$bestTune
   layer1 layer2 layer3
42      2      0      5
```

[image]

Am I doing properly to represent the best neural network? If yes, why in the second option the neurons are not properly displayed?

Comment: Beware as the `caret` tag refers to something different - you should use `r-caret` here (edited).

Comment: Not quite sure if `0` is a valid value for the number of neurons (regardless if it does not throw an error); I would *suspect* that you get similar problematic plots for all cases with `0` neurons in a layer, while otherwise the plots would be fine. Could you possibly confirm this?